# Nonlocal Diffusion Coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In PDE's one typically encounters elliptic problems like:

$$\begin{cases}
\mathrm{div}\left(A(x,u)\cdot \nabla \ u \right)=f, \ \Omega \\
\hspace{12mm} u=g, \ \hspace{20mm} \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
 $$

Where $A$ is a (elliptic) matrix whose coefficients can be understood (via some probabilistic arguments) as parameters which tells us about how nonlinear diffusion works in a possible nonhomogeneous nonisotropic media.

I was wondering if it makes some sense to consider a modification of this problem where the matrix $A(x,u)$ depends in a nonlocal fashion on the $u.$ For example, one could consider the case in which some of the coefficients of $A$ are fractional derivatives of the $u,$ or simply something like $\int_{\Omega}u.$

So, my questions I guess would be:

1) does this have any interest from the point of view of physics and modelization?

2)Has this been studied? What is known about this problem?

Note: I am no expert, nor am I a professional mathematician; I am just asking this out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

A typical constraint you can have is integral. For instance the integral of something is preserved in an area or along a surface. Like Greens theorem. This is a non-local constraint as requiring involves many points in the simulation at once. Also you can use ( switch to ) Fourier bases and derive constraints on the basis functions which are in many cases non-local.